# Automator will only propagate "Home" from an AppleScript list picker through Selected Finder Items

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, mysql

I'm trying to have a user select a primary key from a MySQL database, merge that string at the beginning of a list of selected Finder items, then feed the resulting string into a bash shell script.

It works for exactly ONE primary key, "Home." Is that some sort of reserved word or something? None of the other primary keys I select make it through the process.

Here's a picture of the workflow. You can see at the bottom that "Home" is at the head of the list.

[image]

And here's what happens if I pick anything other than "Home" from the picker:

[image]

Sorry about the hokey window pics. Here's some more detail.

First, I select the primary keys from a MariaDB (MySQL) database, in a "Run Shell Script" portion:

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql \
    --user=GPS_User \
    --password=ReSu_SpG \
    --host=localhost \
    --batch --raw --silent \
    --execute='select `Handle` from GPS_Locations' \
    Personal
```

The "Results" tab shows that's working fine.

Then, I use AppleScript to make a picker, to choose one of the primary keys from the database:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set theHandle to input
    set selectedHandle to choose from list theHandle with prompt "Select a location:"
    return selectedHandle as string
end run
```

Again, based on the Results button, this appears to be working. At this point, there is no visible difference between choosing "Home" (which works) and any other item, which doesn't.

Next, I do "Get Selected Finder Items." It's Results window shows seven items when "Home" was selected as the database key, but only six items when anything else is chosen!

At this point, it really doesn't matter what happens in the next shell script, which is expecting n+1 items, the first of which is one of the keys chosen before, followed by a list of file names.

Any ideas what's going on here, and why Automator seems to be fixated on "Home?"